# Grouping Month End Close Business Dates into a bucket using SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, grouping, dimensions

I'm currently using this logic to figure out these month end close dates

*(defined as last business day of current month, first business day of next month and second business day of next month)*

```
 SELECT             
 CASE 
 WHEN DATE_VALUE IN 
   ( 
     SELECT DATE_VALUE 
           FROM   ( 
                   SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY FIRST_DAY_OF_CALENDAR_MONTH_DATE ORDER BY DAY_NUMBER_IN_MONTH )      AS [MEC1],
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY FIRST_DAY_OF_CALENDAR_MONTH_DATE ORDER BY DAY_NUMBER_IN_MONTH )      AS [MEC2] ,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY FIRST_DAY_OF_CALENDAR_MONTH_DATE ORDER BY DAY_NUMBER_IN_MONTH DESC ) AS [MEC3] ,
                            DATE_VALUE 
                            FROM     DATE_DIM
                            WHERE    RELATIVE_MONTH BETWEEN -13 AND 0
                                     AND      WEEK_DAY_IND = 1 
                                     AND      COMPANY_HOLIDAY_IND = 0 
                          ) d
                          WHERE  MEC1 = 1 -- To get First Day of Business Month
                                 OR MEC2 = 2 -- To get Second Day of Business Month
                                 OR MEC3 = 1 -- To get Last Day of Business Month        
                  ) THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
END AS [MEC_IND]
```

I'm then selecting dates where [MEC_IND] = 1

```
 SELECT 
       Date_Value,
       FIRST_DAY_OF_CALENDAR_MONTH_DATE
FROM ...       
WHERE  C.MEC_IND = 1
```

Using this logic, I've managed to get the dates in this fashion,

[image]

How do I modify the logic to group these Month End close business dates  into buckets like so

[image]

Please keep in mind that I'm using SQL Server 2008 and cannot make use of the LEAD & LAG functions.

Can someone please guide me ? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight-forward way I can think of is to use `dateadd()` with a `case` expression to add one or zero months depending on `day()` and truncating that result to the start of the month.

Using an adhoc date table for this example:

```
declare @fromdate date = '20170428'
declare @thrudate date = '20170704'
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1) 
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
                cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by [Date]
)
select 
    date = [Date]
  , EffectiveMonth = dateadd(month
        , datediff(month, 0
          , dateadd(month,case when day(date) > 27 then 1 else 0 end, [Date])
        )
      , 0)
from dates
where day(date) <4 or day(date) > 27; -- for brevity in results
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/HJXXYL94271

returns:

```
+------------+----------------+
|    date    | EffectiveMonth |
+------------+----------------+
| 2017-04-28 | 2017-05-01     |
| 2017-04-29 | 2017-05-01     |
| 2017-04-30 | 2017-05-01     |
| 2017-05-01 | 2017-05-01     |
| 2017-05-02 | 2017-05-01     |
| 2017-05-03 | 2017-05-01     |
| 2017-05-28 | 2017-06-01     |
| 2017-05-29 | 2017-06-01     |
| 2017-05-30 | 2017-06-01     |
| 2017-05-31 | 2017-06-01     |
| 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-01     |
| 2017-06-02 | 2017-06-01     |
| 2017-06-03 | 2017-06-01     |
| 2017-06-28 | 2017-07-01     |
| 2017-06-29 | 2017-07-01     |
| 2017-06-30 | 2017-07-01     |
| 2017-07-01 | 2017-07-01     |
| 2017-07-02 | 2017-07-01     |
| 2017-07-03 | 2017-07-01     |
+------------+----------------+
```

---

To break down the expression, the main two pieces that are combined are the `dateadd()` that uses a `case` expression to determine if a month should be added (for the last business day of the month) or not (first business days of the month), and the date truncation.

The `dateadd()` with the `case` expression is:

```
dateadd(month
  , case when day(date) > 27 then 1 else 0 end
  , [Date])
```

---

Truncating a date to the first day of the month is simple, though the syntax might not be intuitive. Adding the number of months since `1900-01-01` to the date `1900-01-01` lets us truncate the date to the start of the month.

For example, for the current date:

```
select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate() ), 0)
```

An annotated version of the same expression:

```
select dateadd(month 
      , datediff(month
        , 0 /* '19000101' */
        , getdate() /* date */
        ) /* end of datediff, returns integer number of months */ 
      , 0 /* '19000101' */
      )
```

---

Combining the date trunction with the date we derived with the case expression works out like so:

```
select dateadd(month 
      , datediff(month
        , 0 /* '19000101' */
        , dateadd(month
          , case when day([Date]) > 27 then 1 else 0 end
          , [Date]) /* date */
      ) /* end of datediff, returns integer number of months */ 
  , 0 /* '19000101' */
  )
```

Comment: thank you for your answer I will test it out tonight

Comment: my only additional ask would be if you could add some comments to the logic, I'm not sure I fully understand whats going on here. That would really help. :)

Comment: @kage77 I added an explanation for the expression, let me know if you have any questions.